# why "cd -" in .sh file will print the address

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I use "cd -" to switch between folders.
like:

```
cd /etc/                                                                                                                          
cd -
```

but why "cd -" will print the address(like pwd)?
How can I stop it print the address?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[SUS4 says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/cd.html#tag_20_14_05):

> When a - is used as the operand, this shall be equivalent to the command:
>
> ```
>     cd "$OLDPWD" && pwd
> ```
>
> which changes to the previous working directory and then writes its name.

So, if you don't want the printing half of the behaviour, just do the first bit yourself:

```
cd "$OLDPWD"
```

Or the tilde expansion equivalent

```
cd ~-
```

Often if you need this, `pushd` / `popd` is a better albeit less portable choice.

Comment: +1, don't know why this was downvoted since it certainly explains _why_ it does what it does. Adding the bit that shows how to fix it.

Comment: Dunno. Also added `~-`, `pushd`, `popd`

Answer (score 1):

Just redirect the stdout to black hole like this

```
cd - > /dev/null
```

Comment: I don't like this, because it does double work: first is does a `pwd` which is than redirected to `/dev/null`.  Why not just using `cd $OLDPWD` as ormaaj suggest?

Comment: Because it is more typing? And it uses some 'magic' environment variable? Granted, `cd -` is also a bit magical, but at the very least it is easier to remember.

Comment: This method is fine. It isn't "double work", it's just hiding output (the shell doesn't literally have to run through all the steps necessary to run two commands). You also have to hide output in a similar manner if using `pushd`/`popd` in a script.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is not to use it. Run the commands in a separate shell:

```
(cd /etc/; ... )
```

This does not change the current working directory of the 'main' shell.  This is typically more robust than using `OLDPWD` because you can have many `cd` commands here like

```
(cd /etc; ... ; cd /tmp; ... )
```

Comment: That has different semantics though (especially if `...` changes the environment) and creates an extra process.

Comment: Different semantics to what? IMHO it is completely unclear, what happens between the `cd /etc` and the `cd -`.  If there are environment changes, you are completely right.  If there are additional `cd`s than maybe this is the better way.

Comment: What I mean is that `(cd /etc; FOO=bar)` and `cd /etc; FOO=bar; cd -;` don't do the same thing.